# Why do the income and substitution effects cancel for log preferences? Trouble reconciling Slutsky decomposition

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, consumption, slutsky-equation

I've [read](https://eml.berkeley.edu/~webfac/gourinchas/e202a_f14/Notes_Consumption_pog.pdf) (pg 10) in Gourinchas' notes on consumption that the income and substitution effects cancel for log preferences, and I tried to prove this to myself doing the Slutsky decomposition for the simple case of $U(x,y) = \ln(x) + \ln(y)$ s.t. $p_x x + p_y y = I$. I get that the Hicksian and Marshallian demand functions are $x^* = \frac{p_y}{p_x} y = \frac{I}{2 p_x} $ respectively. Plugging these in gives me this for the decomposition:

$$ \frac{\partial x^*}{\partial p_x} = - \frac{p_y}{p_x^2} y - \frac{1}{2 p_x} \frac{p_y}{p_x} y $$

which is definitely not zero. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Hicksian demand is not a function of income.

Comment: Thanks--edited for clarity. My math is done for $h(\mathbf{p}, \bar{u}) = \frac{p_y}{p_x} y \implies \frac{\partial h}{\partial p_x} = - \frac{p_y}{p_x^2} y$

Comment: When you have $h(\textbf{p},\bar{u})$, shouldn't the stuff on the other side be only a function of the prices and $\bar{u}$? Yet you also have $y$ in $\frac{p_y}{p_x}y$. Perhaps it is this and the missing $\bar{u}$ that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You interpreted the passage you read as essentially saying that **"with log preferences, the Marshallian demand for the good *does not depend on its price*."**
That doesn't sound very plausible, don't you think?

But the passage clearly refers to an intertemporal choice problem, it is about log-preferences over a single good and over time, it does not relate to the Slutsky decomposition of the static Marshallian demand function.

I would suggest to continue reading the notes up to page 14.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking derivative of x* w.r.t. py (which is 0)
And verify with Slutsky decomposition.