# Logarithmic utility and and cancellation of income and sub effects

Tags: income-effect

From [these notes](http://www.econ.yale.edu/smith/econ510a/book.pdf) by Per Krussel on page 16, the author writes that

> "With logarithmic utility, a relative price change between two goods
> will make the consumption of the favored good go up whereas the
> consumption of other good will remain at the same level. The unfavored
> good will not be consumed in a lower amount since there is a positive
> income effect of the other good being cheaper, and that effect will be
> spread over both goods."

I am not quite sure I follow. Imagine that the price of good 1 is 2 and that of good 2 is 1. The relative price of good 1 and good 2 is 2 and income is 10 (we can have money or good 1 can be thought of as the numeraire). The optimal solution, say is 3 units of good 2 and 4 units of good 1. Imagine now, that the relative price changes to *20*, or that the price of good 1 is 1 and good 2 is 20. Of course the unfavoured good here would now be consumed in a lower amount, as there is simply not enough income in terms of the numeraire! What is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do the income and substitution effects cancel for log preferences? Trouble reconciling Slutsky decomposition](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/30709/why-do-the-income-and-substitution-effects-cancel-for-log-preferences-trouble-r)

Comment: Your example is a little confused.  But if you start with the price of good A is 1 and of good B is 2 and with income of 10 and logarithmic utility you have consumption of 4 of A and 3 of B, then if the price of good A stays at 1 and the price of good B changes to 20 and income stays at 10 then you have will have consumption of 4 of A and 0.3 of B; similarly if if the price of good A reduces to 0.1 and the price of good B is 2 and income stays at 10 then you have will have consumption of 40 of A and 3 of B.